# crm 2011 is there anyway to expose the field description text

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm-2011

A CRM field/Attribute has a property called Description.  Has anyone seen a way to expose that property at run-time?  If there were a way through the services API one could place help text in the description and set the tool tip on the form-field on the fly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Description property is available via organization service. Have a look at [SDK.Metadata](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg594428.aspx) library provided by MS - it will allow you to get it via jscript. And this is where supported territory ends :)

To create tooltip with description, you would have to do unsupported modification. Something like [this](http://community.dynamics.com/crm/b/adopt2win/archive/2012/09/14/modifying-tooltips-to-microsoft-dynamics-crm-2011-fields.aspx). Obviously as source of text you would use call to metadata instead of xml resource.

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer. No its not possible in currently available versions. There might be a workaround, but not supported by Microsoft.